# I am found in a pool, never sinking nor afloat; pass the squares that I rule, and a soldier must promote

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *Although I'm a cube, I do not have six sides;*
>
> *Beneath me is green, although no grass resides.*
>
> *My pockets are large enough — I can fall in!*
>
> *But then you'll fall out, though at ends you might win.*
>
> *I'm solid and black, but my pupil is white;*
>
> *My letter and name are as tall as my height.*
>
> *My value is tied, unlike my rotund form.*
>
> *No tees are before you; no spots on me swarm,*
>
> *But I despise stripes even when they're on cue.*
>
> *My pale friend knows me, but what about you?*

A classic riddle of mine. The title is also a clue, but it plays an entirely different game.

---

**Hint:**

> I spin all the time, but will never get dizzy. 
>  Don't count to my number when tipped — it ain't easy.

Comment: @Jannis remember when I told you that I was gonna make a teapot riddle, but didn't? Can you guess what my teapot word might have been, from this riddle? :P

Comment: Dude, I don't think that message will get to @Jannis 's inbox 'cos she's not active in this comment section lol :D

Comment: @KevinL oh. Eh well, I'll just comment on one of her posts I guess :P

Comment: Yeah that should do the trick XD

Comment: @KevinL yeah. I'm surprised this riddle got as many upvotes as it did; I mean, it was pretty easy, or at least not too difficult. Your riddles are good, though :D

Comment: @user477343 I'm here :) you've made it; My guess your teapot was ball(s) :D

Comment: @user477343 Thx :D

Comment: @Jannis yeah, it can be that xD

Comment: @user477343 I'm a freakin [genius](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/genius) :P

Comment: @Jannis that photo, I swear xD. 'Tis a classic photo of you! It should be your profile pic, with you and other funny memes :P

Comment: @user477343 I should have that as profile, but I don't want to, since a) I have the nicest Person in this (actually 'another') world as Profile picture and b) I'm feeling as if I am presumptuous if I had it as Profile picture

Comment: @Jannis heheh, well, in my opinion, it would be funny; though I appreciate your humbleness :P

Comment: @user477343 respect the memes and the memes respect you :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you are

> The black ball in pool

Although I'm a cube, I do not have six sides;

> The ball usually has the number '8' on it which is a cube

Beneath me is green, although no grass resides.

> Pool tables often have a green baize (although it can be blue or red too)

My pockets are large enough — I can fall in!

> Pool tables have pockets

But then you'll fall out, though at ends you might win.

> If you pot the black ball before all others of your designated type, you will lose although you will need to pot at the end to win the game.

I'm solid and black, but my pupil is white;

> The black ball has a small bit of white containing the number.

My letter and name is as tall as my height.

> Not sure about this one, but possibly referencing the similarity between the number '8' and the letter 'B'.

My value is tied, unlike my rotund form.

> The inherent value of the black ball in pool is the winning of the game and not the value '8'.

No tees are before you; no spots on me swarm, 
But I despise stripes even when they're on cue.

> The black ball is neither considered part of the 'spots' or 'stripes' in pool. You use a 'cue' to play the game.

My pale friend knows me, but what about you?

> The cue ball

Hint

> The black ball may spin a lot during play. The number '8' turned on its side is $\infty$, not easy to count.

Title

> *I'm found in a pool* - pool being the game rather than a swimming pool. 
>  *pass the squares I rule* - not sure about this but several of the other balls have square numbers. 
>  *and a soldier must promote* -  an 8-ball is U.S. military jargon for a soldier often in trouble

Comment: Yeah, that's it, however (ROT13) V qvqa'g xabj gur gnoyr pbhyq or oyhr be erq, gbb. Vf guvf ernyy gehr?

Comment: Blue is fairly common and you often see it used in tournaments on TV although red is admittedly more rare.

Comment: Ah, well, you learn something new every day! I play the game at home with a mini table that's green, every now and then. I always thought it was green. Eh well. Also, the other sentences you have not explained are wordplay (with one of them being partially true). Everything else is correct, apart from your $7$th spoiler, and your $8$th one explains one meaning behind the corresponding line :P

Comment: The hint explanation is also correct. You would also need to explain the title. Of course, your answer will be accepted, so do you want me to explain the parts you got not quite right in Rot13, or do you want to figure out those parts yourself? And lastly, the "spots" explanation is incorrect (though it could pass).

Comment: I might think about those for a bit, first.

Comment: Oh, and congratulations for hitting past $30k$ reputation! :D

Comment: Still thinking about the "height, rotund, swarm" parts? :P

Comment: Yes, I guess rotund means round but with the others I'm nor sure.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: (ROT13) "ebghaq" unf n G orsber H, naq bayl tbys onyyf unir fcbgf (be yvggyr ubyrf ba gurz gung ybbx yvxr fcbgf) :D

Comment: You can get pool felt in any color you want.

Comment: @Keltari thank you for the clarification. I did some research and even saw yellow and grey ones. There are at least $40$ different colours of them :P

Comment: The explanation for the title is partly correct. The "found in a pool" part is correctly explained; the "squares" is not (it is an entirely different game) and the "soldiers" is partially correct (you got one of its references, but the other ties in with the squares). I will give you another chance, and if you don't get it, I will just accept and either tell you the answer... or leave it unknown... **Hint:** (ROT13) Gur ahzore ba gur nafjre vf ubj znal fdhnerf gurer ner. Jung vf n tnzr jvgu gung znal fdhnerf nf pbyhzaf (...naq ebjf?) :D

Comment: Eh well, you got your upvotes and its been $2$ days anyway, so congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ :D $\;-$ $\boxed{\small \rm user477343}$ $\tiny \rm Looks \: like \: we'll \: never \: find \: out \: the \: real \: meaning \: behind \: certain \: lines \: of \: the \: riddle, \: hahah$