# Teapot Riddle No. 31

Tags: riddle, word

Since teapot riddles are getting popular, I thought that I should give it a go

> Rules:
>   I have one word which has several (2 or more) meanings
>
> Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
>
> You try to figure out the word with my hints.

Hint  1 :

> My first teapot is possessive
>
> My second is what you have to work on
>
> While the third is dangerous

Hint 2 :

> My first teapot can be self-centered
>
> My second can actually make you rich
>
> The third you have to watch your step *literally*

**Will add more hints in the future**

Comment: Looking at @hexomino 's answer, this was a good word to pick. DVL9 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: @user477343 Thanks. Your teapot riddles are also amazing btw :D

Comment: I can't think of any more teapot words, hahah :P

Comment: @user477343 There are lots of words. You can just search one on the internet :D

Comment: Nah, I try not to. It ruins the fun. At least for me :P

Comment: @user477343 I guess it kinda does :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Mine

My first teapot is possessive

> **Mine** - belonging to me.

My second is what you have to work on

> **Mine** - excavation in the earth for extracting minerals.

While the third is dangerous

> **Mine** - explosive device placed just below the surface of the ground.

My first teapot can be self-centered

> Referring to an object as mine could be considered self-centred.

My second can actually make you rich

> If you are mining for gold or another precious element, finding a large quantity could make you rich.

The third you have to watch your step literally

> If you step on a mine, it can kill you.

Comment: Damn yeah that's correct. Were the hints to straightforward??

Comment: The words "possessive" and "watch your step" made me think of it.

Comment: Although it's always hard to tell with these how hard/easy they are as somebody might just grab on to the right idea straight away.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. But you were too fast mate. Btw, will accept tomorrow :D

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a

> Trap : ([siphon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_(plumbing)) | Trap(music) | a normal trap)
>  110% sure it's the answer :P

because:
Hint 1 :
My first teapot is possessive

> It keeps smell for his own

My second is what you have to work on

> To become a good producer you have to train your skills

While the third is dangerous

> Well obviously traps are dangerous

Hint 2 :
My first teapot can be self-centered

> siphons are self-centred ... I don't know what that means, but yeah siphons are self-centred

My second can actually make you rich

> DJs and Producer can gain much money

The third you have to watch your step literally

> self-explaining

Comment: Hey, remember when I told you that I was gonna make a teapot riddle, but didn't? Can you guess what my teapot word might have been, from [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72925/i-am-found-in-a-pool-never-sinking-nor-afloat-pass-the-squares-that-i-rule-an) recent riddle of mine? :P

Comment: Nice answer but not the intended one unfortunately :D

Comment: @KevinL but it fits in every piece :D, so i guess i have your vote up :)

Comment: Yes, you do actually :D